# Making a datetime aware or naive, without using pytz

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have some issues with django's datetime.

```
from datetime import datetime
d = datetime(2000, 1, 1, <what do i put here, nothing works>) 
# making it aware requires a 4th arg according to the docs, but no matter what
# i enter for that arg, it keeps giving me an error that  tzinfo argument 
must be None or of a tzinfo subclass
```

I can't find anywhere the available options for possible tzinfo parameters that can be passed... and everything online has the pytz module, which isn't on my computer. If it's possible, how can i do this without using pytz?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I was just angry at myself for spending so much time on something like this so I wasn't thinking straight, replace(tzinfo = timezone.utc) with an import for timezone does the trick

Comment: DO NOT USE datetime.replace(tzinfo=timezone) for anything but UTC.
It does not work. use pytz.(timezone).localize(d)